# Matlab Linux error with large clipboard paste

Tags: java, matlab

This error shows in Matlab under Linux whenever I try to paste a large array to matlab:

```
java.io.IOException: Owner failed to convert data
```

There is a [bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7107490) on Oracle's website and there's a workaround to it:

```
Fix: fix code in XSelection.java where, for incremental  dataGetter.dispose() is called before  validateDataGetter(dataGetter); in the method  getData(long format, long time):

               dataGetter.dispose();

                ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(len);

                while (true) {
                    WindowPropertyGetter incrDataGetter =
                        new WindowPropertyGetter(XWindow.getXAWTRootWindow().getWindow(),
                                                 selectionPropertyAtom,
                                                 0, MAX_LENGTH, false,
                                                 XConstants.AnyPropertyType);

                    try {
                        XToolkit.awtLock();
                        XToolkit.addEventDispatcher(XWindow.getXAWTRootWindow().getWindow(),
                                                    incrementalTransferHandler);

                        propertyGetter = incrDataGetter;

                        try {
                            XlibWrapper.XDeleteProperty(XToolkit.getDisplay(),
                                                        XWindow.getXAWTRootWindow().getWindow(),
                                                        selectionPropertyAtom.getAtom());

                            // If the owner doesn't respond within the
                            // SELECTION_TIMEOUT, we terminate incremental
                            // transfer.
                            waitForSelectionNotify(incrDataGetter);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            break;
                        } finally {
                            propertyGetter = null;
                            XToolkit.removeEventDispatcher(XWindow.getXAWTRootWindow().getWindow(),
                                                           incrementalTransferHandler);
                            XToolkit.awtUnlock();
                        }

                        validateDataGetter(dataGetter);
```

However, I don't know what file to modify any java related class to matlab. Where should I look?

Comment: You should file a support ticket with The Mathworks.